# React/webpack conditionally return require.ensure component (code splitting)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

I have a sub component that does not need to be loaded immediately that I want to split out. I am trying to conditionally load in a react component via `require.ensure`. I am not getting any console errors but I am also not seeing anything being loaded.  Here is the code I am calling :

```
renderContentzones() {
if (this.props.display ) {
  return require.ensure([], () => {
    const Component = require('./content-zones/component.jsx').default;

    return (
      <Component
        content={this.props.display}
        />
    );
  });
}
return null;
}
```

It is just rendering a blank screen currently (no errors). This previously worked when I used `import 'displayComponent' from './content-zones/component.jsx'` and just returned it like you normally would in react, instead of this require.ensure but. Not sure what I am doing wrong here, any idea how to make something like this work? Thanks!

Comment: If you do `console.log(Component)`, what do you see in the console? undefined?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, using the state to show the dynamic loaded component:

```
   constructor(){
    this.state = {cmp:null};
   }

   addComponent() {
        const ctx = this;
        require.ensure(['../ZonesComponent'], function (require) {
            const ZonesComponent = require('../ZonesComponent').default;
            ctx.setState({cmp:<ZonesComponent />});
        });
    }

    render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Some info</div>
            <div><button onClick={this.addComponent.bind(this)}>Add</button></div>

            <div>
                 {this.state.cmp}
            </div>
        </div>

    );

 }
```

When you press the button add the component will be shown. 
Hope this help.